# How can I hide the url of flutter application?

Tags: flutter, webview

I don't want the user to see the upper url bar (consisting url and open with web browser). I just want the body content of the website inside my flutter app.Is there any suitable package or a [image]way to solve this?

Comment: You need to make a PWA of your app ! check this :  https://kodytechnolab.com/develop-and-launch-progressive-web-app

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview

To work around issue, in `Pubspec.yaml`

```
flutter_inappwebview:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview.git
      ref: master
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

class InAppWebViewExampleScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InAppWebViewExampleScreenState createState() =>
      new _InAppWebViewExampleScreenState();
}

class _InAppWebViewExampleScreenState extends State<InAppWebViewExampleScreen> {
  InAppWebViewController webView;
  String url = "";
  double progress = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("InAppWebView")),
        //drawer: myDrawer(context: context),
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Text(
                "CURRENT URL\n${(url.length > 50) ? url.substring(0, 50) + "..." : url}"),
          ),
          Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: progress < 1.0
                  ? LinearProgressIndicator(value: progress)
                  : Container()),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              decoration:
                  BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent)),
              child: InAppWebView(
                initialUrl: "https://flutter.dev/", //"https://flutter.dev/",
                //initialFile: "assets/index.html",
                initialHeaders: {},
                initialOptions: InAppWebViewWidgetOptions(
                        crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                          debuggingEnabled: true,
                        )
                    ),
                onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                  webView = controller;
                },
                onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {
                  print("onLoadStart $url");
                  setState(() {
                    this.url = url;
                  });
                },
                onLoadStop:
                    (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) async {
                  print("onLoadStop $url");
                  setState(() {
                    this.url = url;
                  });
                  /*var origins = await WebStorageManager.instance().android.getOrigins();
                      for (var origin in origins) {
                        print(origin);
                        print(await WebStorageManager.instance().android.getQuotaForOrigin(origin: origin.origin));
                        print(await WebStorageManager.instance().android.getUsageForOrigin(origin: origin.origin));
                      }
                      await WebStorageManager.instance().android.deleteAllData();
                      print("\n\nDELETED\n\n");
                      origins = await WebStorageManager.instance().android.getOrigins();
                      for (var origin in origins) {
                        print(origin);
                        await WebStorageManager.instance().android.deleteOrigin(origin: origin.origin);
                      }*/
                  /*var records = await WebStorageManager.instance().ios.fetchDataRecords(dataTypes: IOSWKWebsiteDataType.ALL);
                      for(var record in records) {
                        print(record);
                      }
                      await WebStorageManager.instance().ios.removeDataModifiedSince(dataTypes: IOSWKWebsiteDataType.ALL, date: DateTime(0));
                      print("\n\nDELETED\n\n");
                      records = await WebStorageManager.instance().ios.fetchDataRecords(dataTypes: IOSWKWebsiteDataType.ALL);
                      for(var record in records) {
                        print(record);
                      }*/
                },
                onProgressChanged:
                    (InAppWebViewController controller, int progress) {
                  setState(() {
                    this.progress = progress / 100;
                  });
                },
                /*onUpdateVisitedHistory: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url, bool androidIsReload) {
                      print("onUpdateVisitedHistory $url");
                      setState(() {
                        this.url = url;
                      });
                    },*/
              ),
            ),
          ),
          ButtonBar(
            alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                onPressed: () {
                  if (webView != null) {
                    webView.goBack();
                  }
                },
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                onPressed: () {
                  if (webView != null) {
                    webView.goForward();
                  }
                },
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
                onPressed: () {
                  if (webView != null) {
                    webView.reload();
                  }
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ])));
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: InAppWebViewExampleScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you can also check this plugin [flutter webview plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin)

Comment: thank you this plugin worked for me. I have another question. Did you see the pay now button inside the webview? I want to pop the app page on clicking the pay now button instead of rerouting a new page in the web view.Is it possible?